# Optimizing spark sql query

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am using this below query to derive outliers form my data. using distinct is creating too much shuffle and the end tasks are taking huge amount of time to complete. are there any optimization that can be done to speed it up?

```
query = """SELECT
DISTINCT NAME,
PERIODICITY,
PERCENTILE(CAST(AMOUNT AS INT), 0.997) OVER(PARTITION BY NAME, PERIODICITY) as OUTLIER_UPPER_THRESHOLD,
CASE
WHEN PERIODICITY = "WEEKLY" THEN 100
WHEN PERIODICITY = "BI_WEEKLY" THEN 200
WHEN PERIODICITY = "MONTHLY" THEN 250
WHEN PERIODICITY = "BI_MONTHLY" THEN 400
WHEN PERIODICITY = "QUARTERLY" THEN 900
ELSE 0
END AS OUTLIER_LOWER_THRESHOLD
FROM base"""
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest rephrasing this so you can filter before aggregating:

```
SELECT NAME, PERIODICITY, OUTLIER_LOWER_THRESHOLD,
       MIN(AMOUNT)
FROM (SELECT NAME, PERIODICITY,
             RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY NAME, PERIODICITY ORDER BY AMOUNT) as sequm,
             COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY NAME, PERIODICITY) as cnt,
             (CASE . . .  END) as OUTLIER_LOWER_THRESHOLD
      FROM base
     ) b
WHERE seqnum >= 0.997 * cnt
GROUP BY NAME, PERIODICITY, OUTLIER_LOWER_THRESHOLD;
```

Note:  This ranks duplicate amounts based on the *lowest* rank.  That means that some `NAME`/`PERIODICITY` pairs may not be in the results.  They can easily be added back in using a `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: Am i missing something here? the field OUTLIER_UPPER_THRESHOLD

Comment: @shibu . . . I just left that logic out -- there are `. . .`s for it.  It is not relevant to the performance issue.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to deal with a large shuffle, independent of what the shuffle is, is to use a larger cluster. It's the easiest way because you don't have to think much about it. Machine time is usually much cheaper than human time refactoring code.

The second easiest way to deal with a large shuffle that is the union of some independent and constant parts is to break it into smaller shuffles. In your case, you could run separate queries for each periodicity, filtering the data down before the shuffle and then union the results.

If the first two approaches are not applicable for some reason, it's time to refactor. In your case you are doing two shuffles: first to compute `OUTLIER_UPPER_THRESHOLD` which you associate with every row and then to distinct the rows. In other words, you are doing a manual, two-phase GROUP BY. Why don't you just group by NAME, PERIODICITY and compute the percentile?

Comment: can you  provide the sample query that you mentioned for the last approach